# Bootstrap table containing buttons not responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am currently working on something, and my problem is that my table isn't responsive, most likely because of the buttons I am using. The other tables are showing up fine.

Screen: [image: Screenshot]

Code:

```
<tr>
                                <td><? echo $sLa['id']; ?></td>
                                <td><? echo $sLa['Name']; ?></td>
                                <td><? echo $sLa['Modell']; ?></td>
                                <td><? echo $sLa['Version']; ?></td>
                                <td><? echo $sLa['IP']; ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="registeroverview.php?id=<?php echo $sLa['id']; ?>&kid=<?php echo $lID; ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Detail</button></a>
                                    <a href="editregister.php?id=<?php echo $sLa['id']; ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-warning btn-xs">Bearbeiten</button></a>
                                    <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-danger btn-xs">Löschen</button></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

The last `td` contains the buttons.
Does anyone know how I could make that table responsive?

Comment: What class You use for table?

Comment: I am using the following, like for all my tables on that page: `class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover"`

Comment: Try to add class="table-responsive"

Comment: If you read the documentation, you'll see that you put a div around a table with the class "table-responsive"

Answer (score 1):

The table-responsive class suggested in the comments makes the table have a horizontal scroll bar inside it, which may be what you are looking for.

Tables themselves don't really 'respond', the table you have is already the smallest it will get - its the content inside the table that forces it to be that wide - check this: http://zurb.com/article/982/a-new-take-on-responsive-tables

> Tables have a magical property that says they can never be so small
>   that parts of a word have to be cut off — they can't overflow. That
>   means that, when your design shrinks down for the width of, say a
>   smartphone, large data tables will ensure your design doesn't actually
>   shrink all the way down.

Comment: it wasn't meant to make your table responsive, it was meant to show you that tables and responsive design don't always work, and to get them to work is hard work.

Comment: You need to put `table-responsive` on the table's **parent**, not on the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
      <td><? echo $sLa['id']; ?></td>
      <td><? echo $sLa['Name']; ?></td>
      <td><? echo $sLa['Modell']; ?></td>
      <td><? echo $sLa['Version']; ?></td>
      <td><? echo $sLa['IP']; ?></td>
      <td>
             <div style="width: <PUT_YOUR_PIXEL_SIZE>">
                  <a href="registeroverview.php?id=<?php echo $sLa['id']; ?>&kid=<?php echo $lID; ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Detail</button></a>
                  <a href="editregister.php?id=<?php echo $sLa['id']; ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-warning btn-xs">Bearbeiten</button></a>
                  <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-danger btn-xs">Löschen</button></a>
             </div>
      </td>
</tr>
```